# Continuous Image of non-converging sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a complete normed vector space,  $\{x_k\}_{k\geq 1} \subset X$ a sequence  and $A: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded linear operator such that:
$$ \lim_k\,A(x_k) = 0$$

> Q: If $\{x_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ is not converging what is the meaning of the previous identity?

If $x_k$ is definitely in the null space of $A$ then it is obvious, in particular if $A \equiv 0$. I'm wondering in which other nontrivial cases this can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem about the meaning? It's just a sequence of real numbers converging to $0$.

For instance, suppose that $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, with its usual norm. Let $A(x,y)=x$. Consider the sequence defined by $x_k=\left(\frac1k,(-1)^k\right)$ ($k\in\mathbb N$).
The sequence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ doesn't converge, but$$\lim_{k\to\infty}A(x_k)=0.$$

Comment: Oh sure! This is enough, I was going for some weird examples but this one is simple and quite neat!

Answer (score 0):

A more complicated example might be the following:

$X=L^{\infty}([0,1])$  with the essential-supremun norm and $x_k(t)=t^k$ for $t\in [0,1]$ and define the functional $A:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $$Ax=\int_0^1x(t)dt.$$
Then $\{x_k\}_k$ doesn´t converge since $$||x_k-0||_{\infty}=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|t^k|=1$$
for every $k$. $A$ is obviously a bounded linear functional and $$Ax_k=\frac{1}{k+1}\rightarrow 0$$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$.